# Gem Binaries not found with oh-my-zsh

Tags: zsh, ruby, rubygems, oh-my-zsh

I'm using Oh-My-Zsh on Mountain Lion and have an issue with gem binaries not loading properly.

For instance:

[image]

If I load a new shell the binary still cannot be found.  When using Bundler, I can load binaries, but only with a prefixed `bundle exec`.

What's up?

Comment: You do a `gem install pry`, etc., so I am going to ask, are you using `RVM`?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `$GEM_HOME` is in your `$PATH`. If it isn't, your gem executables won't be available through your path.

Comment: doesn't work in arch/zsh